# FOR loop range to process certain number of files at a time

Tags: python, loops, range

I have a for loop that runs through a directory and processes the files there, but I'd like to only process a certain number of the files at one time. For example, I have a directory with 1000 files, but I can only process 250 of them a day, so the first time I run the script, it processes the first 250. then the next 250, and so on and so forth.

First, I'm checking the file names against an XML file that records the name of files that have already been synced, so that I don't process them a second time. Then I would like to process the next n files, where I have a variable `synclimit = n`

I thought about adding the in range statement to the for loop like this:

```
tree = ET.parse("sync_list.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
synced = [elt.text for elt in root.findall('synced/sfile')]
for filename in os.listdir(filepath) and in range (0, synclimit) :
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '*.txt') and filename not in synced:
    filename = os.path.join(filepath, filename)
    result = plistlib.readPlist(filename)
```

But, I'm pretty sure this will only check the first n number of files in the directory each time. Should I add the range statement to the if statement? like:

```
tree = ET.parse("sync_list.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
synced = [elt.text for elt in root.findall('synced/sfile')]
for filename in os.listdir(filepath):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '*.txt') and filename not in synced and in range (0, synclimit):
    filename = os.path.join(filepath, filename)
    result = plistlib.readPlist(filename)
```

or is there an easier way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep a separate counter and increment that, then test if it has reached `synclimit`. Simple as that. There is no need to get too clever here:

```
processed = 0
for filename in os.listdir(filepath):
    if not filename.endswith('.txt') or filename in synched:
        continue
    # process
    processed += 1
    if processed >= synclimit:
        break  # done for today.
```

Alternatively, since `os.listdir()` returns a list, you could filter it if you have your already synched list of filenames in a set, then slice it down to your maximum size:

```
synced = set(elt.text for elt in root.findall('synced/sfile'))
to_process = [f for f in os.listdir(filepath) if f.endswith('.txt') and f not in synched]

for filename in to_process[:synclimit]:
    # process
```

Note that I just test for `.endswith('.txt')` instead of using your simple filematcher; the test comes down to the same thing.

Comment: Both much more elegant solutions than what I came up with. My only concern is interrupted processes. The last part of my script emails files using google smtp, which is notorious for terminating connections. I have the send function wrapped in a while loop with a sleep, so if it fails, it should try 3 more times before giving up. But there are occasions when I have to start the script over. So I have the XML save today's date as an attribute alongside the filenames. Then I build a count of elements whose attribute = today. Then, build synclimit dynamically with synclimit = 250 - syncedtoday.

Comment: Use a proper (local) MTA instead. It'll spool your email messages as needed and send when Google is good and ready.

Comment: Documentation on how to implement this? Thank you.

Comment: @sosukeinu: Golly, too many ways. Look at postfix, exim, etc. Plenty that can be set up as a forwarding (or satellite) MTA, some Linux distributions have specific recipes for that setup.